# The composition of a homotopy and a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I feel like I have some fallacies, please help me clear them. About something that seems to be very basic.

> Say we have a homotopy $h:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $h(x,t)=tx$. Then there is this quotient map $q:[0,1]\to S^1$ that identifies $0$ and $1$. Hence compositing them gives a continuous map $qh:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to S^1$ that is a homotopy from a loop in $S^1$ to the constant map, so does it follow that the loop $f(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is nullhomotopic? Or which part is wrong?

Comment: The space $S^1$ itself is not a loop and a map to $S^1$ is not necessarily a loop. A map **from** $S^1$ is a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could say your $f$ is homotopic to the constant map on “$[0,1]$,” but the loop $S^1$ is not. To show a loop is homotopic to another, your domain should be $S^1,$ not an interval.

Comment: But the loop is nullhomotopic right? Being nullhomotopic only requires homotopy to a constant map (not necessarily relative to boundary point)?

Comment: Yes. I should fix what I said. Please see my edited version.

Comment: That is to say, though the image of your $f$ is $S^1,$ it is not the loop we usually talk about.

Comment: So the concept of homotopy between loops should correspond to path homotopy (fixing initial and final points) rather than the general notion of homotopy?

Comment: No. It’s in your usual sense of homotopy. But the domain should be $S^1$ (and that’s why we call they loops).

Comment: I leave the crucial part now to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Any *path* $[0, 1] \to X$ is a nullhomotopic map, no matter if its image has self-intersections. So
$$
[0,1] \to S^1 : \;  t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}
$$
is nullhomotopic.

But *loop* is a map of the form $S^1 \to X$. The loop
$$
S^1 \to S^1 : \;  t \mapsto t
$$
is not nullhomotopic.